# Connecting to MSAccess with Java

Tags: java, database, ms-access, connection

I am developing my project in Java. I would like to know how I can connect to MSAccess.
Any links, or small examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) is a good tool to read MSAccess databases without ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with using UCanAccess (http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) which allows both read and write access to the database

Comment: For more information, see the related question: [Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390).

Answer (score -2):

I used this article, on [javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-09/03-qa-0922-access.html) when I first started JDBC programming. And may I suggest using pure Java DB's or MySQL's or Oracle's personal editions unless you have a specific need for MS Access.